# How could i call a object from the class point so that i can use it in rectangle

Tags: python, function, class, rectangles

I wanted to call the x and y point from a the class point and implement it in the class rectangle so that i would input x,y,w,h and it would print a point(x,y) with a certain height and width and also print an area.

an example of what it is supposed to produce is

Rectangle at(3,2) with height = 2 width = 1 , area = 2

however, I kept getting this error on line 22:

```
 __str__
    result += str(self._X)+ ',' + str(self._Y) + ')'
AttributeError: 'rectangle' object has no attribute '_X'
```

This the current code I had:

```
import math
import sys
import stdio

class Point(object):
     def __init__(self, x, y):
          self._X = x
          self._Y = y

class rectangle:
     def __init__(self,x,y, w, h):
        self._h = h
        self._w = w

     def area(self):
          a = self._h * self._w
          return a

     def __str__(self):
          result = 'Rectangle at('
          result += str(self._X)+ ',' + str(self._Y) + ')'
          result += ' with height = ' + str(self._h)
          result += ' width = ' + str(self._w)
          result += ' , area = ' + str(self.area())
          return result


def main():
     x = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
     y = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
     w = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
     h = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
     
     rect = rectangle(x,y,w,h)
     stdio.writeln(rect)

     
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: You use the term calling a variable. It does not mean what you think it means.Please stop that.

Comment: Also, well done for including a reasonable error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to create a Point in your rectangle:

```py
class rectangle:
     def __init__(self,x,y, w, h):
        self.point = Point(x, y)
        self._h = h
        self._w = w

     def area(self):
          a = self._h * self._w
          return a

     def __str__(self):
          result = 'Rectangle at('
          result += str(self.point._X)+ ',' + str(self.point._Y) + ')'
          result += ' with height = ' + str(self._h)
          result += ' width = ' + str(self._w)
          result += ' , area = ' + str(self.area())
          return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle has attribute _h and _w only. Self refers to the rectangle object. You need to add the missing attributes _x and _y or use inheritance from point.

Answer (score 0):

The Rectangle class can herit from Point and you may also initialize it in Rectangle.**init**

```
class rectangle(Point):
     def __init__(self,x,y, w, h):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self._h = h
        self._w = w

     def area(self):
          a = self._h * self._w
          return a

     def __str__(self):
          result = 'Rectangle at('
          result += str(self._X)+ ',' + str(self._Y) + ')'
          result += ' with height = ' + str(self._h)
          result += ' width = ' + str(self._w)
          result += ' , area = ' + str(self.area())
          return result
```

but i think that it's better to use composition as it's specify in the first answer